# I want to be able to select multiple options in the dropdown, how can I change my code to do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, my dropdown looks like this. I can only select one of the options. I want to be able to select multiple options when clicking. I tried adding `multiple` in `<select>` but that doesn't work. How can I make the dropdown allow multiple selections?

[image]

```
const SelectMultipleDropdown = props => {
  const {
    name,
    required,
    placeholder,
    handleChange,
    choices,
    value,
    fieldValid,
    setFieldValid
  } = props;
  const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = useState("");

  // the default value is empty string ""
  // invalid/greyed out value is empty string ""
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="field-component-title">
        {name}
        {required ? <span className="required-star"> *</span> : ""}
      </p>
      <select 
        className={`dropdown-select-field field-component-input-box ${
          currentSelection === ""
            ? "dropdown-select-grey"
            : "dropdown-select-black"
        } ${(() => {
          return fieldValid ? "" : "dropdown-select-invalid";
        })()}`}
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          e.persist();
          setCurrentSelection(e.target.value);
          handleChange(e);
          setFieldValid(true);
        }}
        value={value}
      >
        <option value={""}>{placeholder}</option>
        {choices.map(({ value, text }, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={value}>
            {text}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this component, your current Selection is a string, and use `setCurrentSelection(e.target.value);` can change currentSelection to another option.

You can change string to array, for instance, currentSelections. And change setCurrentSelections function to:

```
  setCurrentSelections = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let currentSelections = this.state.currentSelections.slice(0);
    let index = currentSelections.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      currentSelections.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      currentSelections.push(value);
    }
    this.setState({ currentSelections: currentSelections });
  }
```

And use React Component

```
class SelectMultipleDropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSelections: [],
    }
  }

  setCurrentSelections = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let currentSelections = this.state.currentSelections.slice(0);
    let index = currentSelections.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      currentSelections.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      currentSelections.push(value);
    }
    this.setState({ currentSelections: currentSelections });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    this.setCurrentSelection(e);
    this.porps.handleChange(e);
    this.props.setFieldValid(true);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      required,
      placeholder,
      choices,
      value,
    } = props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="field-component-title">
          {name}
          {required ? <span className="required-star"> *</span> : ""}
        </p>
        <select 
          className={''}
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={value}
        >
          <option value={""}>{placeholder}</option>
          {choices.map(({ value, text }, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={value} selected={this.state.currentSelections.includes(value)}>
              {text}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am keep getting `Error: "setCurrentSelections" is read-only` could you please show the example in the full code that I posted?

Comment: Ok, I rewrite my answer. And @DCTID answer is right too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear on the error or undesired behavior you get here. But, here's my try. First `multiple` works a bit weird depending on browser and OS as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).
I'm guessing that's not what you're describing tho. I'm guessing the problem is that you are 1. overwriting all your selected and 2. not mapping `selected` to your options.
So you need to start with an empty array for your selected elements if nothing is selected, then add to that array in the `onChange()` instead of overwrite the value there and finally add `selected` to the `option` when it's in your list of selected elements.

I would also add it appears you are storing the value at this level component and a higher level component thru a callback. It is generally a best practice to store the value in one spot. I'm not sure the best place from this bit of code. That might be best in another question.

```js
  const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="field-component-title">
        {name}
        {required ? <span className="required-star"> *</span> : ""}
      </p>
      <select 
        className={`dropdown-select-field field-component-input-box ${
          currentSelection === ""
            ? "dropdown-select-grey"
            : "dropdown-select-black"
        } ${(() => {
          return fieldValid ? "" : "dropdown-select-invalid";
        })()}`}
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          e.persist();
          setCurrentSelection((current) => [...current, e.target.value]);
          handleChange(e);
          setFieldValid(true);
        }}
      >
        <option value={""}>{placeholder}</option>
        {choices.map(({ value, text }, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={value} selected={currentSelection.includes(value)}>
            {text}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note: if you want to support super old browsers you'd need to replace `includes(currentValue)` with `indexOf(currentValue) > -1`